# Does an infinite line segment make any sense?

Tags: geometry, infinity, fractals

In school, I was taught that a line segment must be finite. But a fractal has an infinite perimeter. If you just took two points along that perimeter, and "stretched it out" wouldn't you have an infinite line segment?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I guess it depends what you mean by "stretching it out". It's not like these things physically exist, so there'd have to be some kind of mathematical operation that would do whatever it is you're picturing. And, whatever these operations did, it couldn't possibly produce a straight line segment, with two endpoints, while preserving length.

Comment: Adding to Theo's comment, on a fractal such as the Koch snowflake, the distance "along the curve" between _an arbitrary pair of points_ on the curve is infinite.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you mean.  Is a line and "infinite line segment"?